# How to link a Ethereum token as a file?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, nft, erc-721, ipfs

With IPFS you get a file hash for every file you store in it, I want to create a DAPP that is based on IPFS storage and link an ERC20, ERC721, etc. or even NFT to the ipfs hash file.

***It's possible?***

For example, it creates a new file and the user implements a smart contract function that mints a token and it is created at the same time as the IPFS file.

Answer (score 0):

For an ERC721 token (NFT or non-fungible token), linking an IPFS url is pretty standard. Each ERC721 token created is unique so each can have their data.

ERC20 becomes a bit more complicated since ERC20 is fungible, meaning that each token can divided into smaller parts. As a work-around you could assign a link to each user that owns any amount of tokens. I can't think of a way where each token is assigned a url.

https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/mint-nfts-with-ipfs/